# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Unsupported Audio Format

Tags: javascript, python, audio, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am developing a web app in ASP.net Core MVC.

I am trying to record audio in Javascript through the users microphone and I achieve this by using `MediaRecorder()`. I send the blob with the audio data to the backend where I receive the data in the form of IFormFile.

Script to record audio:

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(async function (stream) {
        var recordButton = document.getElementById("record-button");
        var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop-button");

        var microphone = await audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
        var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        var destination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

        recordButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            gainNode.connect(destination);
            recorder.start();
            recordButton.disabled = true;
            recordButton.style.pointerEvents = "none";
        });

        stopButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            microphone.disconnect();
            gainNode.disconnect();
            recorder.stop();
        });

        recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => 
        {
            var blob = event.data;

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('audioBlob', blob);
            formData.append('sentence', $('#sentence-input').val());

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ProcessAudio", "Sandbox")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#modalContent').html(data);

                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
            });
        };
```

I then receive the data, copy it to a byte array, save it in a Temporary File in the desired sample rate that Microsoft Cognitive Services asks for, and send it to my API in Python where I invoke Microsoft's tool.

```
@app.route("/pronunciation-assessment", methods=["POST"])
def pronunciation_assessment():
    audioFile = request.files['audio_data']
    reftext = request.form.get("reftext")

    audioFile.save("audio.wav")

    audioFile = open("audio.wav", "rb")
    def get_chunk(audio_source, chunk_size=1024):
        while True:
            chunk = audio_source.read(chunk_size)
            if not chunk:
                break
            yield chunk

    referenceText = reftext
    pronAssessmentParamsJson = "{\"ReferenceText\":\"%s\",\"GradingSystem\":\"HundredMark\",\"Dimension\":\"Comprehensive\",\"EnableMiscue\":\"True\"}" % referenceText
    pronAssessmentParamsBase64 = base64.b64encode(bytes(pronAssessmentParamsJson, 'utf-8'))
    pronAssessmentParams = str(pronAssessmentParamsBase64, "utf-8")

    url = "https://%s.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=%s&usePipelineVersion=0" % (region, language)
    headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json;text/xml',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
    'Content-Type': 'audio/wav; codecs=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    'Pronunciation-Assessment': pronAssessmentParams,   
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'Expect': '100-continue'
}

    response = requests.post(url=url, data=get_chunk(audioFile), headers=headers)

    audioFile.close()

    return response.json()
```

I have done unit testing on this endpoint prior with just a standard .wav file that was stored locally and it worked out fine. Furthermore, upon listening to audio.wav, I observe that everything was saved correctly and the audio is playable.

However, when I return the `response.json`, I get

> Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

And upon close inspection, the content of `response` is b'Unsupported audio format'

What shall I do?

Comment: Please correct your indentation. It's not clear what lines belong in which function. You also have an unindented `return` statement at the bottom.

Comment: @MattDMo  Done. Im sorry

Comment: I would not be suprised that your MediaRecorder is not recording with these settings: 'audio/wav; codecs=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000. Can you provide parameters / options to the MediaRecorder? Or ensure a conversion on your API side maybe

Comment: @NicolasR I cannot provide parameters to MediaRecorder, no. Yes, I can and have successfully communicated with the API with Curl and C#.